# Is it possible that my laptop can have 2 internal hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, bios

I recently check my BIOS during startup.
I saw 2 HDD slot and 1 FDD. One HDD is my default hard drive, while the second HDD do not have a label.
I'm wondering if there's a possibility that the one HDD without label can be used as my second hard drive.

Comment: What laptop is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question highly depends on the laptop you own. And the answer to this has two parts: BIOS and hardware.

The BIOS reports the number of drives it can handle which is 2. This is because the first HDD controller could handle 2 drives and therefore the BIOS up to date can also handle 2 drives (for compatibility reasons).

In laptop it depends on the size if you can house 2 HDDs. Most laptops with 15" or less have only 1 HDD bay whereas some larger latops could house 2 HDDs (e.g. I've a Dell Inspiron 1720 which houses 2 HDDs).